# Crystal Reports 2011 - Case Statement with multiple variables

Tags: crystal-reports

I need a CASE statement in Crystal to set two Variables for each CASE in the statement, but I haven't figured out if it is possible and if so, how.

**For Example**

```
Shared NumberVar StandardWeekDay
Shared NumberVar BusinessWeekDay

select {Command.DayofWeek}
Case "Monday" :
*StandardWeekDay := 1 AND BusinessWeekDay :=2*
Case "Tuesday" :
*StandardWeekDay :=2 AND BusinessWeekDay :=3*
```

and so on and so forth ... I've tried separating the two variables with an **AND** or with a **comma**, but neither one worked.  Is it possible to set two variables within a CASE in Crystal?

Comment: In CR, statements are ended with a `;`. Use parentheses to delineate your statement blocks and end each statement within those blocks with a semicolon and you should be able to get this to work.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
Shared NumberVar StandardWeekDay;
Shared NumberVar BusinessWeekDay;


    select {Command.DayofWeek}
    Case "Monday" :
    (
        StandardWeekDay := 1;
        BusinessWeekDay :=2;
    )
    Case "Tuesday" :
    (
        StandardWeekDay :=2;
        BusinessWeekDay :=3;
    )
```

Note how the AND was stricken from the code and how the semicolon that Ryan mentioned is put at the end of the first expression.

Comment: In your solution you need end the variable decleration with `;` aswell